# RN: Navigationbar - How to change title from Rightbutton

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

Not sure why this doesn't work - I want to have a Textinput in the NavigationBar-Title and a Button to clear the input in the "RightButton". But code should explain this:
I have a simple Navigator (simplified here):

```
      <Navigator
                ref="navigator"
                navigationBar={
                   <Navigator.NavigationBar
                     style={styles.nav}
                     routeMapper={ NavigationBarRouteMapper } />
                 } />
```

with a TextInput (for searching) in the Title, and an Icon to clear the input.:

```
var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
  RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
   if(route.name=='Search') {
    return (
     <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor="transparent"
        onPress={() => this.refs.searchTextInput.clear() }>
      <Icon
          name={"clear"}
          size={24}
          color="#777777"
          style={styles.rightNavButton} />
     </TouchableHighlight>
    );
 }

 Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
  if(route.name=='QuestionList' || route.name=='Search'){
   return (
    <TextInput
      ref="searchTextInput"
      style={ styles.searchBar}
      autoFocus = {(route.name!='Search')? false : true}
      onFocus={
          (route.name!= 'Search')?
              ( index<2?
                () => navigator.push({name: 'Search', enableBackButton: true})
              :
                ()=> navigator.pop()
              )
          :
              null }
      onChangeText={(text) => {route.sendTextToModule(text)}}
      placeholder='Ask...'/>);
    }
}
```

error is: undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this2.refs.searchTextInput'). Seems like it's not in the scope, but yeah.. never properly learned JS :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a state for textinput value will make you get rid of this complexity. Add a **state** called xTextInputValue=' '  in **constructor**.

- onChangeText={(text) => {**navigator**.props.setTextValueX(text)}}//**TextInput oncChangeText**
- titleText= {this.state.xTextInputValue}// add    this prop in
  your **navigator** component
- setTextValueX = ( (val) => this.setState(xTextInputValue:val)// add
  this method in your **navigator** component

that's it. onChangeText will call navigator's setTextValueX function and this function will refresh the value meanwhile titleText value will be refreshed during the same render.

//your new navigator component

```
  <Navigator
             ref="navigator"
             titleText= {this.state.xTextInputValue}
             setTextValueX = ( (val) => this.setState(xTextInputValue:val)
             navigationBar={
              <Navigator.NavigationBar
                style={styles.nav}
                routeMapper={ NavigationBarRouteMapper } />
           } />
```

Comment: ehm.. where would I have to add "titleText= {this.state.xTextInputValue:val}" ? can't get it to work but I like the idea

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.xTextInputValue') - on the             titleText= {this.state.xTextInputValue} line

Comment: did you add the state in constructor?

Comment: Yes - this.state={xTextInputValue:''}